# Execute <script ...></script> several times with javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

Say we have the following script reference

```
<script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js"></script>
```

How to make javascript execute it several times on page load, like (in pseudo code):

```
<script>
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
         <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js"></script>
     }

</script>
```

Comment: may be one way to put your loop logic in side osd.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to achieve what you need.

```
<script>
   var elem = document.createElement('script'); 
   elem.type = 'text/javascript'; 
   elem.async = true;
   elem.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js';

   for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[i];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, s);
   }
</script>
```

This should load as well as execute the script. @BenM

Comment: This will just append `<script>` 5 times, not execute the code defined in the external JS 5 times.

Comment: I agree with @BenM, say in the <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js"></script> you have code that executes immediately. And I want this code to execute several times.

Comment: Good solution to use `elem.async`. +1

Comment: @BenM, rectified the async loading. Hope this helps the OP

Comment: What if the script tag has arguments?
<script async src="https://...." data-my-post="aaa" data-width="100%"></script>

Comment: Add a switch case inside for loop.

Comment: @Aditya could you please again give an example?

Answer (score -1):

First of all I didn't understand why are you trying to add reference to same js file repeatedly. Its enough if you load the file only once. If you are trying this to execute some code inside the js file then just write that piece of code inside a function and call that function on window onload. Hope that helps

Comment: Where is your "Second..."? You wrote "First of all..." :D